# Importing mlab from mayavi or vtk : the kernel died

Tags: kernel, anaconda, vtk, mayavi, mayavi.mlab

I have tried installing mayavi for several days, without results. I'm using spyder and anaconda. I can import mayavi on spyder without problem, but when I try importing vtk or from mayavi import mlab, the kernel died. I read a lot on the subject without finding a solution that work. I try all backend (Online, Qt4 and Qt5) without result. I'm still new to Python so I'm not quite sure if I did all the installation right.

To install mayavi I use :

`$conda config --add channels conda-forge`

`$conda install mayavi`

I also try to use 
 `$ pip install mayavi`
but I get another error that I was not able to solve : Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1. (which I also try to solve without result doing all the update recommended)

I try these tests :

`$nosetests -v tvtk/tests`     ERROR: Failure: OSError

`$nosetests -v mayavi`         ok

---

### **System infos** (Windows 10)

- anaconda                  5.2.0
- conda                     4.5.7
- mayavi                    4.6.1
- PyQt5                     5.11.2
- python                    3.6.5
- spyder                    3.2.8
- vtk                       8.1.0

If someone has a solution that would be great!

Comment: Have you found a workaround? I'm having the same problem nowadays but on ubuntu 20